# Can i receive money on PayPal account without a linked bank account

Tags: money-transfer, online-banking, paypal

I have a PayPal account but I'm about to be paid without a bank account linked can I receive the money and spend it

Answer (score 3):

You can receive money on any PayPal account. You can spend them at businesses that accept paypal payments. You can also transfer them to a VISA card (it is not the same as a bank account).